# Codeigniter Form Validation : order of validation rules

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have a form validation rule of something like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|strip_tags|xss_clean|callback__name_check');
```

Now if anyone enters `<p></p>` or equivalent (empty tags), the result will be empty, but somehow required rule will pass as well, resulting in blank name when inserting to database.

I can do an extra check before inserting, but I wonder if there's a way in CI to prevent that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to switch `required` and `strip_tags` in this rule?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|strip_tags|required|xss_clean|callback__name_check');
```

Comment: was pretty sure I tried it to no avail, but now after I changed the order of the rules, it works! :) Thanks

Comment: You should move it after xss_clean as well. Unfortunately I believe xss_clean inserts "[removed]", maybe you can set it to an empty string or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the strip_tags rule (not appear in the codeigniter user guide) and try with:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|prep_for_form|xss_clean|callback__name_check');
```

I think that this is usefull for you

User guide says:

```
prep_for_form

Converts special characters so that HTML data can be shown in a form field without breaking it.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html
```

Comment: no good, since it passes the `<p></p>` and when I convert it to slug, the slug will be empty because I'm using url_title to slug it.